# Pokemon go account switch

Tags: pokemon-go

Im currently playing Pokemon go on my mother's account. I want to know if I can save my Pokemon and items and transfer to my account. I'm not sure if I made one but if I do, I want to transfer the progress from my mom's account to mine.

Answer (score 3):

You can log out and log into another account, keeping progress from both separate. You cannot however, transfer progress from 2 accounts at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue, as I started playing on my kid's iPad and then....well....I got hooked and wanted my own account.  You cannot transfer progress from 1 account to another, but you can log into the account from your device.  So, if you want to keep playing I suggest just keeping your mom's log in on your phone....but if she wants to play too, she will need to set up a new account (or steal hers back).